# como posso fixar esse menu no topo,?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, menu

Eu estou com um site com um menu que fica abaixo do meu `header`, *150px* abaixo do topo da tela.

Gostaria de fazer com que quando eu rolasse a pagina e o menu do site chegasse a posição `0` do topo ele ficasse fixado e rolasse só o restante do conteúdo meu site.

Comment: Penso que é isto que voçe quer Veja este link http://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/

Comment: Relacionadas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129367/menu-fixo-com-jquery-em-determinada-rolagem-scroll-da-p%C3%A1gina , https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108746/como-adicionar-o-logo-no-menu-fixo-depois-de-uma-certa-rolagem-na-pagina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso vc pode usar o `position:sticky` e repare que vc precisa de um `z-index` setado para o conteúdo não ficar por cima da barra. Aqui tem um link com a documentação: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#sticky-pos

Vou te dar um modelo prático que acho que vai te ajudar. Repare que quando a barra chegar no topo ela vai ficar fixa, mas quando rolar para baixo ela vai mover. Não precisa de JavaScript é puro CSS

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
section{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
p {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 80px;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50px;
}
.cor {
    font-size: 32px;
    background-color: red;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h3>Meu header</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
</header>
<section>
    <h1 class="cor">Barra #2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
</section>
```

Aqui vc pode conferir quais Browsers aceitam o position:sticky https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky